# Long time to upload app to emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

It's taking a very long time to upload an app to the emulator, typically several minutes. When I was developing an app for iOS, Xcode would upload the app to iOS Simulator **within seconds!** Why is it taking so long for the Android emulator? And what can I do to speed it up?

Comment: I use Motodev Studio on a Mac Air, and running an app on the emulator or device is practically instantaneous.

Comment: What software are you using to develop? Are you starting the emulator every time you ant to run your app or do you reinstall your app without shutting the emulator off?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse under Windows 7. I try not to restart the emulator every time. Even so, it still takes several minutes to upload the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an android phone to plug in and run your app on that, its much quicker than the emulator. Unfortunately the emulator is just pretty slow, there may be things you can do to speed it up slightly, such as keeping it running between tests rather than shutting it down each time, but the best bet is to test on a phone!

Comment: Very true. Not closing the emulator between tests cuts out the boot up time, but the thing still lags. If you plan to a fair amount of android programming, I would recommend getting a physical device. Kinda funny that Apple gets you with the price of publishing to the app store whereas android has such a bad emulator that they almost force you to buy a device.

Comment: At least in Canada, Android phones are very expensive. Typically, you need to sign up for a 3-year contract. I can't afford a couple of thousand dollars for phone contract.

Comment: I suppose I could look for a cheap, prepaid Android phone. It probably wouldn't be a very good model, though -- some low-end crap. It's best to use a decent phone with decent features.

Comment: You could try and pick one up second hand for cheaper. Depends how much programming you're going to be doing really.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

Go to Run -> Run Configurations... -> Target Tab -> Additional Emulator Command Line Options. Add there:

```
-netspeed full -netdelay none
```

After doing this the time for uploading went from 2 minutes to 8 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

HAX is way much faster than normal simulator. Of course, testing device is the best option since some of the features are harder to test on simulator (for example, Gyro, Accelerometer, etc... )